# What to do in this case in Python 3?

Tags: python

I get the message shown in the headline when I run the code. Could anybody explain why the code does not return the details of the BankAccount object. I do run similar code in Java, it works. I use do-while & switch cases in Java.  `<__main__.BankAccount object at 0x0151F0A0>`. I tried to apply `if __name__ == "__main__"` but it give the same message on the console.
I tied to comment function by function, but still the same result. Even IDE does not find any error in this code. The code is correct. I do make a mistake, which I can not find out. Why I don't get similar result on console?

```
class BankAccount:
    balance = 0
    amount = 0
    previous_transaction = 0

    def __init__(self, customer_name, customer_id):
        self.customer_name = customer_name
        self.customer_id = customer_id

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.amount = amount
        if self.amount != 0:
            self.balance += amount
            self.previous_transaction = amount
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if self.amount != 0:
            self.balance -= amount
            self.previous_transaction = -amount

    def get_prev_trans(self):
        if self.previous_transaction > 0:
            print("Deposited: " + str(self.previous_transaction))
        elif self.previous_transaction < 0:
            print("Withdrawn: " + str(abs(self.previous_transaction)))
        else:
            print("No transaction occurred")

    def show_menu(self):
        option = input()
        amount_input = input()
        print("Welcome " + self.customer_name)
        print("Your ID is " + self.customer_id)
        print("\n")
        print("A ==> Check Balance")
        print("B ==> Deposit")
        print("C ==> Withdraw")
        print("D ==> Previous Transaction")
        print("E ==> Exit")

        while True:
            if option == "A":
                print("..............................................")
                print("Balance = " + str(self.balance))
                print("..............................................")
                print("\n")
                break

            elif option == "B":
                print("..............................................")
                print("Enter an amount to deposit: ")
                print("..............................................")
                self.deposit(amount_input)
                print("\n")
                break

            elif option == "C":
                print("..............................................")
                print("Enter an amount to withdraw: ")
                print("..............................................")
                self.withdraw(amount_input)
                print("\n")
                break

            elif option == "D":
                print("..............................................")
                self.get_prev_trans()
                print("..............................................")
                print("\n")
                break

            elif option == "E":
                print("**********************************************")
                print("Thank you for using our services.")
                break

            else:
                print("Invalid Option! Please, enter again.")
                break

account1 = BankAccount("RGA", "0911")
print(account1)`
```

Comment: First off, It's useful to remember that python is not java. You will be actively hindering your progress if you attempt to write Java in python. Secondly, if you ask your code to print the object itself, it's showing you exactly what you asked it to do in python-land.

Comment: @RGA What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: This is a Banking Account App, which should give these results. 
Welcome RuslanGasimli
Your ID is 911


A ==> Check Balance
B ==> Deposit
C ==> Withdraw
D ==> Previous Transaction
E ==> Exit
==============================================
Enter an option
==============================================

Answer (score 2):

You need define method `__str__(self)` for text representation your object